# sonarqube Failed to start after connecting with mssqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Did everything correct as per this [post](http://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/blog/DevOps/Install-SonarQube-As-WindowsService-With-SQLServer-WindowsAuth-VSTS-TeamBuild) - But no definite error is logged.

***Sql - server Connection String -*** 
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://SUNIL-DELL;databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=true

**Error -**

```
 F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\bin\windows-x86-64>startsonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2017.02.17 12:35:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\temp
jvm 1    | 2017.02.17 12:35:36 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\temp\sq-process8223413915559248642properties
jvm 1    | 2017.02.17 12:35:49 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2017.02.17 12:35:49 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\lib\jdbc\mssql\sqljdbc42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\temp\sq-process4020298620991371426properties
jvm 1    | 2017.02.17 12:36:09 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2017.02.17 12:36:09 ERROR app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] failed to start
jvm 1    | 2017.02.17 12:36:10 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

**Log: -**

```
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.02.17 12:35:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\temp
2017.02.17 12:35:36 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\temp\sq-process8223413915559248642properties
2017.02.17 12:35:49 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2017.02.17 12:35:49 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\lib\jdbc\mssql\sqljdbc42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer F:\sonarqube\sonarqube-6.2\temp\sq-process4020298620991371426properties
2017.02.17 12:36:09 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2017.02.17 12:36:09 ERROR app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] failed to start
2017.02.17 12:36:10 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Check SonarQube logs under _<sonar_install_dir>/logs/_ to get more details. Especially _web.log_ should shed some light on what's happening here. Then update your question with your findings.

Comment: Got the issue - web.log - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').

Answer (score 0):

If *web.log* shows this (per your comment):

> org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.')

Then it means that SonarQube was not able to connect to the database using the provided URL and credentials. Usual checks:

- verify connectivity to the database host
- verify database name
- verify credentials

If still clueless, suggest to run a simple database client on the same machine as where SonarQube runs, to better diagnose any URL/credential issue (as the underlying problem here is independent from SonarQube itself).

Answer (score 0):

Let me first show you the versions that I was using and what should be set and where to help you guys how to configure it

**Sonar Version :** sonarqube-8.9.10.61524

**Java Version :** 11 and 17 both are installed but this uses 11 as mention in wrapper

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Properties file**

[image: sonar properties file changes]

[image]

[image]

**SQL Server:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Sonar :**

[image]
[image]

Hope this would help, Cheers!